# How can I remove the lock icon from Android lockscreen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, lock-screens

Here is an image for reference. I want to remove the three arrows that are pointing upwards. I have no problem with rooting my device. I just don't know where to find these thumbnails and delete them. Can anyone help me to locate them?Will their deletion pose any issues?

[image]

The app is native `keyguard.apk` and the image files are under `system/priv-app/keyguard.apk/res/drawable/ic_blinkscr_midbright.png`

I have download root explorer but it does not show any option to delete the file. It just shows open and extract option. I have no idea how to delete it.

Comment: What's you device, Android version, and is this the native lockscreen (doesn't look like so - I've never seen a native lock that doesn't even show your wallpaper and battery status) or a lock app from a third party?

Comment: @AndyYan I did some research on my own. I am adding additional details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already found the resource file to the arrow inside the APK, all you need to do now is to replace it with a transparent one. Root or custom recovery is required, and custom recovery is personally *recommended*, because there is a slight possibility that this will throw you into a bootloop, so having a backup in recovery prior to mods would be handy.

Sometimes simply extracting the APK, replacing it and repackaging it could work (this has been the case for me for simple framework mods). If custom recovery is available, trying this is fast and won't hurt.

The safer way is to decompile the package while keeping its signature. [Virtuous Ten Studio](http://virtuous-ten-studio.com/) is a friendly way to get your hands on this without getting lost in the command lines of APKTool - the site also has simple tutorials.

After modification and repackaging, overwrite the original one and set correct permissions (usually rw-r--r-- (0644)). Reboot for changes to take effect.

And at last - do not simply delete the file, or whenever the file is used, the app will error out, possibly leaving you with endless Force Close dialogs.

Comment: Thanks @AndyYan. I copy `keygaurd.apk` and paste it in my SD card's root directory but when I connect the device to a PC, I don't see any `keyguard.apk` that I can copy and edit.

Comment: @NeenaVivek That's another problem on its own... Try moving the file around on the SD card (into other dirs); also try uploading the file somewhere from the phone and pull it from your PC. There's another way (`adb pull`) but since I don't know whether you have ADB right now I'll just skip it.

Comment: I have moved it to a few directories but it doesn't show up anywhere.  There is no option to share it via shareit etc. either. The sharing option is disabled. I will try something else though. :)

Comment: @NeenaVivek compress/zip it, it helps for me.